# How to achieve the equivalent of "Fn::Contains" in a Conditions block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The situation here is that we're auto-generating a CFT YAML file, and the number of Resources of a particular type (call it `Thing` here) is running into AWS quota limits.  But any specific deployment of the CFT will not actually need all of those `Thing`s, and by making the `Thing`s conditional, this project can stay well under those limits.

So given a Parameter like

```yaml
Parameters:
  OptionParameterList:
    Description: This is an elegant and lyrical description of The Option.
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    AllowedValues: [ 'OptionA', 'OptionB', 'OptionC', ..., 'OptionZZ9PluralZAlpha' ]
    Default: 'OptionX'
```

(Ideally, this would be presented as a drop-down list with checkboxes, but that only works for the built-in `List<AWS::EC2::Whatever>` types, not for `CommaDelimitedList`.  Instead, they see a textbox where they can type possibilities and the CFN parser splits the inputs on commas.)

What I'd like to do is something like

```yaml
Resources:
  ThingControlledByOptionA:
    Condition: <whether they included OptionA in the parameter>
    Type:  ...
    Properties: ... things involving A ...
  ThingControlledByOptionB:
    Condition: <whether they included OptionB in the parameter>
    Type:  ...
    Properties: ... things involving B ...
  ...
```

and so on.  We do a lot of that already and it works great.  The challenge this time is that I can't figure out how to implement the Condition blocks.

I *think* I want something like

```yaml
Conditions:
  OptionACondition: Fn::Contains [[ !Ref OptionParameterList ], 'OptionA' ]
  OptionBCondition: Fn::Contains [[ !Ref OptionParameterList ], 'OptionB' ]
  ...
```

which uses the [syntax for `Fn::Contains` described in the CFN user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-rules.html#fn-contains).  The problem is that `Fn::Contains` is only available to `Rules` sections, not to `Conditions` sections.  (Why?  Who knows.)

The [list of functions usable for conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html) is extremely limited.  Is there a way of playing with or `CommaDelimitedList` to achieve this?

(The next best thing might be to generate a true/false parameter for each of the options, but that's going to get unwieldy kind of fast.  I understand that the *actual* answer is "CloudFormation is too limited to do anything programmatic, switch to something like Terraform instead" and I'm hoping to just find enough of a solution to buy us time to do exactly that next year.)